# UIImage unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone

I have the 'classic' error:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance.

If I read through other comparable questions it should be memory related, however I can't find out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is what I try to do:

- crop an image
- give the image rounded corners

I use the brilliant [code of Trevor](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/)

This is my code:

The `roundedCornerImage:borderSize:` is giving the trouble

```
NSInteger my_borderSize = 0.1;
UIImage *Image_large = [image_sel croppedImage:CGRectMake((my_width/2) -(my_height*0.66)/2, 0, my_height*0.66, my_height) ];
UIImage *roundedCornerImage_temp = [Image_large roundedCornerImage:0.8 borderSize:my_borderSize];
```

Comment: Can you post the declaration from .h and definition from the .m so we can see what else is happening in roundedCornerImage:borderSize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is not in Apple's `UIImage` class.  They are extensions to `UIImage` written by the guy whose code you link to.

You need to make sure to add **UIImage+RoundedCorner.h** and **UIImage+RoundedCorner.m** to your Xcode project, and then in the class where you want to use `roundedCornerImage:borderSize:`, you should

```objc
#import "UIImage+RoundedCorner.h"
```

Also, I notice that you're passing in decimal values for both `cornerSize` and `borderSize`.  Those are supposed to be `NSInteger` values, per Trevor's API.  I would guess that those are in display *points*, but apparently, he limited it to integer values.

**Update:** also make sure that the UIImage+RoundedCorner.m file is listed among your **Compile Sources**:

[image]

Comment: What I had to do is the following: remove the .m and .h files and add them once again. Although the files where visible in the classes directory, there was something wrong. Could this be caused by upgrading the project to the new sdk some time ago? Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @user1926467, that's possible.  Also, in Xcode, there needs to be the understanding that those files (specifically, the .m) are to be **compiled**.  You can check on that by clicking on your project, then the build **Target**, and then on the **Build Phases** tab, look under **Compile Sources**.  See update above for a screenshot.